# nan shows up on my boxplot but there is no column labeled nan?

Tags: python

I started with:

```
print(NAsales_boxplotdf)
```

and I got the following output:

```
              Genre  NA_Sales
0            Sports     41.49
1          Platform     29.08
2            Racing     15.85
3            Sports     15.75
4      Role-Playing     11.27
...             ...       ...
16594       Shooter      0.01
16595        Racing      0.00
16596        Puzzle      0.00
16597      Platform      0.01
16598           NaN       NaN

[16599 rows x 2 columns]
```

I then pivoted the the dataframe as follows:

```
NAsales_boxplotpivot = NAsales_boxplotdf.pivot(values = 'NA_Sales', columns = 'Genre')
```

to get:

```
Genre  NaN  Action  Adventure  Fighting  Misc  Platform  Puzzle  Racing  \
0      NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   
1      NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN     29.08     NaN     NaN   
2      NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN   15.85   
3      NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   
4      NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   
...    ...     ...        ...       ...   ...       ...     ...     ...   
16594  NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   
16595  NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN    0.00   
16596  NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     0.0     NaN   
16597  NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN      0.01     NaN     NaN   
16598  NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   

Genre  Role-Playing  Shooter  Simulation  Sports  Strategy  
0               NaN      NaN         NaN   41.49       NaN  
1               NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
2               NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
3               NaN      NaN         NaN   15.75       NaN  
4             11.27      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
...             ...      ...         ...     ...       ...  
16594           NaN     0.01         NaN     NaN       NaN  
16595           NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
16596           NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
16597           NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  
16598           NaN      NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN  

[16599 rows x 13 columns]
```

I dropped the NaN column using:

```
NAsales_boxplotpivot[NAsales_boxplotpivot.columns.dropna()]
```

to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFPTj.jpg) and then I put put it in a boxplot using:

```
NAsales_boxplotpivot.plot(kind='box', rot = 90, figsize = (20,10), showfliers = False)
```

to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bz3f.jpg).

Comment: NaN often means "Not A Number", and is often obtained by performing some floating point operation that is illegal or indeterminate.  I can not tell you how that concept explains you getting a column with that name. - Are you performing floating point operations in your code that might be ending up in your table logic?

Comment: Could you give your full code, you have probably done some maths which produces weird output, for eg. what is 1 / 0? There is no such number... it's nan(although most languages give a ZeroDivisionError instead of outputting nan).

Comment: I edited my post to show my steps. I didn't do any math as far as I can tell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFPTj.jpg) you posted, you displayed

```
NAsales_boxplotpivot[NAsales_boxplotpivot.columns.dropna()]
```

using Jupyter notebook, but you did not store the result in NAsales_boxplotpivot. However, you used NAsales_boxplotpivot to create the boxplot. Thus, the boxplot is created from the original dataframe with the NAN column.
To remove the NAN column and store the result you'd need to write

```
NAsales_boxplotpivot = NAsales_boxplotpivot[NAsales_boxplotpivot.columns.dropna()]
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.